# sys_read call linux error values

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly programming.I have written an assembly program to read characters from input file to buffer and convert it into upper-case letter and generate an output file.I have used int80h service to read character from the input file.I want to add a functionality to check error values returned by sys_read call incase it fails to read a character from input file.How to do that?what register will contain the error values and what values will show error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recollection (it's been awhile since I did system-call-level programming) is that `sys_read` returns either the number of characters read, 0 if at end of file, or an error code less than zero in case of error, and that that return value is passed via the usual `%eax` register (`%rax` on x86-64, I think).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I will do some research on what you have suggested.